# Factorio: How to play programmable speaker when train stopped?

Tags: factorio

This seems so simple but I admit I can't figure it out. I am trying to set up a circuit to play a programmable speaker when the train arrives at the station in Factorio but I have no experience with the circuit network yet. I tried connecting the train stop directly to the speaker, and connecting the train stop to all combinators and messing around with the logic. I have "Read stopped train" option selected on the train stop when a circuit is attached.  My output signal is "F".  My train is on automatic schedule.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should work just fine. I've just made a test setup and it worked. Here's what I did:

1. Created a train stop and placed a programmable speaker next to it
2. Connected them with green wire
3. Opened the settings of the station to specify 'Read stopped trains' and output to signal 'T'
4. Opened the speaker and set it to go off when `T > 0`.

Now, my guess is that your speaker is checking for the input signal `F == 1`, but the train at the stop has its own unique number, so it's probably not 1. Try changing that to `F > 0`.

In images:
[image: Station setup]

*Station setup*

[image: Station configuration]

*Station configuration*

[image: Speaker configuration]

*Speaker configuration*